# Update angular scope when adding editorTemplate in .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

I am working with a project in .Net MVC and we are using EditorTemplates to dynamically add fields to our form. In one of these fields I want a function to trigger when the value is changed. I tried to solve this with angular (ng-change) but the event do not trigger on the  new added field. But if I save the form and then edit the field again the event is triggered. So it seems to me that the scope, or the angular model, is not updated when we add html elements through the EditorTemplate.

Is there a solution for this or do I have to forget about angular in combination with .net MVC?

Comment: Could you post some code?